# Nested calculation with javascript & Angular (v1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object like that:

```
vm.data = {
        a : {
            v : 25
        },
        b : {
            v : "",
            c : "f + a"
        },
        c : {
            v : "",
            c : "b + a"
        },
        d : {
            v : "",
            c : "c + e"
        },
        e : {
            v : "",
            c : "a + c"
        },
        f : {
            v : "",
            c : "b + c"
        }
    };
```

and I would like to have all these calculations done every time I change A.
I cannot find a solution to solve this problem. Any idea?

PS: this is just an simple example of an object hundreds time bigger and complicated than this.

Comment: why not use some function or getters?

Comment: do you have stored in some place which change triggers which calculations ? or are they harcoded in code or something ?

Comment: @NinaScholz: can you give an example of a getter please?
Gonzalo.- : I've got a service with this data and I've to calculate all these values every time I change one of them (in this case only A).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [getter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for getting an actual value of the calculation of the properties.

```js
var object = {
        a: 6,
        b: 42,
        get c() { 
            return this.a + this.b;
        }
    };
    
console.log(object.c);
object.a = 1000;
console.log(object.c);
```

```js
var object = {
        a : 25,
        get b () { return this.a * 5; },
        get c () { return this.b + this.a; },
        get d () { return this.c + this.a; }
    }; 
    
console.log(object.d);
object.a = 1000;
console.log(object.d);
```

Comment: it's a very good solution and it works well...I have just to find a way to change my original object in this way. The biggest problem is that I have to use parseInt to get numbers, otherwise it sees the values like strings.
Thank you.

PS: Any other suggestion is very welcome (I would like avoid to change the original object)!

Comment: PSS: it works in this way:
vm.data = {
            a :  25,
            get b () {
                return this.a * 5
            },
            get c () {
                return parseInt(this.b) + parseInt(this.a)
            },
            get d () {
                return parseInt(this.c) + parseInt(this.a)
            }
        };

but it doesn't work if, in c, a change this.b with this.d because d is calculated afterwards (I presume) ...and I have scenarios like that unfortunately.

Comment: you need the right order and prevent circular references.